# void respond_to format.html Only should works with format.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, respond-to

I want void **format.html response in controller in ruby on rails 3.**

e.g. in my comments_controller.rb

```
def new
 @comment = Comment.new
  respond_to do |format|
    #format.html # new.html.erb avoid this output
    #format.json { render json: @board } # avoid this output
  format.js
 end
end
```

I want only works with **format.js response** and after, render partial from new.js.erb. This is not problem for me its easy, but...

If I put:

http://localhost:3000/comments/new

I get a blank page :O.

**How can I void this page? e.g. render or show a error 404.**

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like:

```rb
def new
 @comment = Comment.new
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render text: "Error", status: 404 }
    #format.json { render json: @board } # avoid this output
  format.js
 end
end
```

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html for full details.